# Azure Function Apps: how to deploy on a different plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Once my function apps are developed and exported as a zip file is there an effective way to import the apps (as a zip file) to a different app service plan?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bunch of info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy

You can go to `<different-app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole`, navigate to wwwroot, and drag/drop your zip to unpack the bits in your new website.

Also, if you want a more automated solution, you can drop your zip in a blob and use an ARM template with the `packageUri` property: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md#create-arm-template

Personally, I'd use git to shuffle the bits around so that you can set up continuous deployment and have the benefits of version control.